# Variadic template for taking multiple containers references

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, variadic-templates

I want to have a function taking multiple references to containers and returning the element-wise combination of all of them. Since this operation is performed in an extremely hot loop I would like to be able to unroll as many operations as possible statically without writing 5 instances of basically the same function.

The algorithm I am performing basically behaves as

```
const auto result = s0 + a1 * s1 + a2 * s2 + ...
```

Where all of the `si` are containers containing all the same number of elements. The number of elements to sum over is known at compile-time.

The function I am looking for should behave as: (hypothetically)

```
inline Container sum(const Container& s0, double a1, const Container& s2, ....){
    auto result = Container(s0);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i)
        result[i] += a1 * s1[i] + a2 * s2[i] + ...;
    return result;
}
```

For performance reasons it is not desirable to write some inner loop with runtime bounds checks. Also when trying to use runtime bounds I encountered the issue of not being easily able to pass a variable number of references to the function, should I just resort to pointers in that case.

All code needs to be valid C++11, I do not have access to a more modern compiler in this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would group `double` and `container` to simplify code to:

```
template <typename C, typename ... Cs>
C sum(const C& c0, const Cs&... cs)
{
    auto result = c0;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i)
#if 0 // C++17
        result[i] += (cs[i] + ...); 
#else // C++11/C++14
        const int dummy[] = {0, (static_cast<void>(result[i] += cs[i]), 0)...};
        static_cast<void>(dummy); // avoid warning for unused variable.
#endif
    return result;
}
```

So, for the grouping, something like:

```
template <typename C>
struct MulContainer
{
    auto operator [](int i) const { return d * c[i]; }

    double d;
    const C& c;
};
```

So for call, instead of

```
sum(c0, a1, c1, a2, c2);
```

you would have:

```
sum(c0, MulContainer{a1, c1}, MulContainer{a2, c2});
```

If really needed, with `std::index_sequence` you may still have first call syntax.

```
template <typename C, std::size_t... Is, typename Tuple>
C sum_impl(const C& c0, std::index_sequence<Is...>, const Tuple& t)
{
    return sum(c0, MulContainer{std::get<2 * Is>(t), std::get<2 * Is + 1>(t)}...);
}

template <typename C, typename ... Ts>
C final_sum(const C& c0, const Ts&... ts)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) % 2 == 0);
    return sum_impl(c0, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) / 2>{}, std::tie(ts...));
}
```

`std::index_sequence` is C++14 but can be implemented in C++11.

Comment: In the function sum() you have the syntax:
            result[i] += (cs[i] + ...);
I believe this is not C++11, is it? still these are some good ideas, thank you

Comment: Indeed C++17 implementation. You might have similar result in C++11/C++14 with more verbose syntax.

Comment: C++14 version added. for C++11, I let you find `index_sequence` implementation.

Comment: `sum_impl` and `sum` could be merged into one single function just having `result[i] += ((std::get<I * 2>(t) * std::get<I * 2 + 1>(t)[i]) +  ...);` (C++17 variant) in the for loop, dropping the intermediate struct...

Comment: @Aconcagua: I think splitting code make it more clear and more generic (we can have `sum(c0, c1, c2, MulContainer{a3, c3}, ReverseContainer{c4});`), but indeed, code can be modified that way.